# Generalizing concept of content of a polynomial to commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A $ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $f,g\in A [x] $. Let $I_1,I_2, J $ be the ideals generated by the coefficients of $f,g,fg $ respectively. Must $J $ be equal to $I_1 I_2$ ?

It is an exercise an Atiyah and Macdonald to show that this true in the case  $I_1=I_2=A $.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, consider $A=\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]/(ad+bc)$ and $f=ax+b$, $g=cx+d$.  Then $fg=acx^2+bd$, so $J$ is just $(ac,bd)$.  But $I_1I_2$ contains $ad$, which is not in $J$.  (You can prove $ad\not\in J$, for instance, by noting that $A$ is a graded ring with $|a|=|b|=|c|=|d|=1$ so if $ad$ were a linear combination of $ac$ and $bd$ the coefficients could be taken to have degree $0$.)

Answer (score 4):

$f=ax+b$, $g=ax-b$, choosing $a,b$ so that $(a,b)^2\neq (a^2,b^2)$.